# Problema al realizar consulta dinámica en Hibernate con campo que pertenece a la clave

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-ee

Tengo un portlet en Liferay que necesita hacer una búsqueda a través de varios campos. Para eso utilizo una Conjunction.

Actualmente la Conjuntion es así:

```java
Conjunction conjUbicacion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.conjunction();
            conjUbicacion.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("idProvincia", pointRequest.getIdProvincia()));
            conjUbicacion.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("idVia", pointRequest.getIdVia()));
            conjUbicacion.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("descripcionNumero", pointRequest.getDescripcionNumero()));
            dqUbicacion.add(conjUbicacion);
```

Este código realiza una búsqueda correctamente pero obtengo más datos de los que quiero porque tengo que añadir una restricción más sobre un campo que se llama idMunicipio.

Al añadir idMunicipio el código queda del siguiente modo:

```java
Conjunction conjUbicacion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.conjunction();
            conjUbicacion.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("idProvincia", pointRequest.getIdProvincia()));
            conjUbicacion.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("idMunicipio", pointRequest.getMunicipio()));
            conjUbicacion.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("idVia", pointRequest.getIdVia()));
            conjUbicacion.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("descripcionNumero", pointRequest.getDescripcionNumero()));
            dqUbicacion.add(conjUbicacion);
```

Al ejecutar este portlet obtengo este error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: idMunicipio
```

Mirando en el fichero xml module-hbm.xml me encuentro que esa tabla está definida del siguiente modo:

```xml
    <composite-id class="es.dxd.center.search.back.service.persistence.UbicacionPK" name="primaryKey">
            <key-property name="idUbicacion" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.LongType" />
            <key-property name="idMunicipio" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.LongType" />
        </composite-id>
        <property name="idVia" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.LongType" />
        <property name="tipoVia" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.StringType" />
        <property name="descripcionVia" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.StringType" />
        <property name="descripcionNumero" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.StringType" />
        <property name="localidad" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.StringType" />
        <property name="idProvincia" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.LongType" />
        <property name="refCatastral" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.StringType" />
        <property name="coordX" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DoubleType" />
        <property name="coordY" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DoubleType" />
        <property name="latitud" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.StringType" />
        <property name="longitud" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.StringType" />
        <property name="idZonaESO" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.LongType" />
        <property name="idZonaBTO" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.LongType" />
        <property name="idZonaCFGS" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.LongType" />
        <property name="idZona" type="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.LongType" />
```

Si busco por cualquiera de los que están definido como <property> me permite buscarlo pero tengo la sensación de que en este caso que está definido como <key-property> y que es una clave compuesta no me permite acceder.

¿Sabéis si estoy en lo cierto? ¿Se puede añadir a la conjunción de alguna manera este campo que pertenece a la clave?

**YA LO HE RESUELTO**

Pongo aquí la respuesta porque he intentado poner la respuesta y tengo bloqueado el responder preguntas

Al final he encontrado una referencia en esta dirección 
[Using the Dynamic Query API](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/using-the-dynamic-query-api)

En esta página indican lo siguiente:

```
The gotcha is that some of Liferay's objects use composite keys. When using composite keys with Hibernate's detached criteria and Liferay's dynamic queries, the name of the property must include the name of the composite key. In the case of the Hibernate definitions created by Liferay's Service Builder, composite keys are always named primaryKey.

Therefore, the solution is to use primaryKey.userId instead of userId.

Criterion criterion =
    RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("primaryKey.userId", userId);
```

Es decir, que sí que se pueden añadir los campos de una clave compuesta a un criterio de una consulta dinámica, pero que hay que acceder como **nombreDelCompositeId.campo**.

En mi caso, el composite-id tiene nombre primaryKey, así que tuve que añadir

```java
conjUbicacion.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("primaryKey.idMunicipio", pointRequest.getMunicipio()));
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Se agradece que expliques cómo se resolvió para los que vengan después, pero en vez de editar la pregunta es mejor que lo añadas como respuesta y la marques como respuesta aceptada.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, pero intenté responder la pregunta y me salió que tenía bloqueado responder preguntas. Imagino que porque todavía no tengo suficiente reputación

Comment: Yo te recomendaría no usar llaves compuestas, siempre usa un id entero único que no tenga nada que ver con el negocio. Si te vez en la necesidad de usar llaves compuestas quiere decir que tu modelo relacional esta mal diseñado. Lee esto: [Cómo elegir la clave primaria de una tabla](https://inmensia.com/blog/20070223/elegir_clave_primaria_tabla_base_datos_oracle.html)

Comment: @abrahamhs Buen aporte. En este caso es un desarrollo heredado y no se podía cambiar la estructura de base de datos